# How to get Interfaces belongs to IID's, IConnectionPoint, IConnectionPointContainer in ANSI C

Tags: c, com

I've created a Connection between client and COM Object with help from IConnectionPoint & IConnectionPointContainer.

```
data->pApp->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(data->pApp, &IID_IUnknown, (void**)&data->pUnknown));
data->pUnknown->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(data->pUnknown, &IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&data->pConnectionPointContainer));
data->pConnectionPointContainer->lpVtbl->FindConnectionPoint(data->pConnectionPointContainer, &DIID__IApplicationEvents, &data->pConnectionPoint));
data->pConnectionPoint->lpVtbl->Advise(data->pConnectionPoint, (IUnknown*)sink, &sink->dwCookie));
```

I've already implemented QueryInterface, AddRef & Release. 
If the COM Object will execute QueryInterface I printf the riid.

```
IID: 0x3 - 0x0 - 0x0 - 0x764D3E14
This-Objekt: 0030EC4C, ppvObject: 0030E2D4

IID: 0x3 - 0x0 - 0x0 - 0x764D3E14
This-Objekt: 0030EC4C, ppvObject: 0030E294

...
```

How can I find out which Interfaces belong to the IID's?

---

EDIT:

I would love to compare the IIDs to something i know using the suggested `IsEqualGUID`
but i do not know what interfaces are called by my target application.

```
if(IsEqualGUID(iid, &IID_IThisIsWhatIAmLookingFor))
```

I try to find out what interface the numbers i get are belonging to, so i try to find the interface `IID_IThisIsWhatIAmLookingFor` based on the numbers i get. Implementing this is the next step for me.

Comment: Consult the documentation for the target application. You will need that documentation to know how to implement the interface anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find out which Interfaces belong to the IID's?

You cannot tell `IID` from interface pointer you are holding. In code, you typically manage pointers in the variables specific to certain interfaces, and you obtain the values there using respective `IID`s.

What you however can is another `QueryInterface` call with `IID` of interest. Note that you cannot assume that you get the same pointer every time, unless `IID` is `IID_IUnknown`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, the interface is Automation compatible and a Typelib exists. In this case, the registry contains an entry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\TypeLib`, pointing to an entry below `HRCR\Typelib`, which references a .tlb file that you can import.

The alternative is entering the IID into Google in the various typical forms:

- `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
- `00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000000`

Comment: thanks this helps a little bit - but still i try to find out what Interfaces i need to implent. I edited the question.

Comment: How i can import a .tlb file in ANSI-C?

Comment: Convert to .idl, then generate headers as normal.